# While loop in eclipse bpel

Tags: eclipse, soa, bpel

I don't know how to make a while loop in Eclipse BPEL. I have this variable:

```
<bpel:variable name="counter" type="ns1:int">
    <bpel:from>1</bpel:from>
</variable>

<bpel:while name="While">
    <bpel:condition expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </bpel:condition>
    <bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign2">
    </bpel:assign>
</bpel:while>
```

How can I set the loop's condition and increment the variable counter inside the loop?
I need beginner's doc from BPEL.